# Socket reading and timestamps

Tags: c, sockets, timestamp, system-calls

When reading from a (non-stream) socket in Linux, I can get the (hardware-generated) timestamp of the last received message via a `ioctl(sock, SIOCGSTAMP, &tv)`. However, this poses two problems:

- It is another syscall (I'm receiving about 24000 messages per second, so each syscall is notifiable)
- If using this approach, I can only `read()` one message at a time, followed by the `ioctl()` to get the timestamp. (If I'm reading more than one message in a `read()`-call, the following `ioctl` only yields the timestamp of the last message.)

My question is how to achieve receiving messages and their timestamps in as few syscalls as possible. It would be perfect if there was a syscall with semantics like "read as much messages as are pending and their timestamps".

Comment: Did you find a solution to your syscall problem?

Comment: The accepted solution below is a solution; it just happens I could not use it because of my very old kernel version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`recvmmsg(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmmsg.2.html) system call, if available with your kernel, and set [`SO_TIMESTAMP`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/socket.7.html) option.

Comment: Ah, I only ever encountered recvmsg, not recvmmsg. Thanks!

Comment: How I may access the timestamp with recvmmsg?