# Obtain packet timestamp through ioctl call on socket file descriptor

Tags: c, sockets, embedded-linux

I'm working on a system running embedded linux. I'm trying to obtain the packet timestamp from a stream I'm receiving on a socket.

After creating the socket, I do the following:

```
if (fd != -1) {
    int enabled = 1;
    setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TIMESTAMP, &enabled, sizeof(enabled);
}
```

After that I bind the socket, the socket is of type SOCK_STREAM. I successfully receive data on the socket, by calling the function `recv(fd, buf, size, 0)`. Now in order to obtain the timestamp of the received data, I'm currently trying the following:

```
ret = recv(fd, buf, size, 0);
if (ret > 0) {
    struct timeval tv_ioctl;
    tv_ioctl.tv_sec = 0;
    tv_ioctl.tv_usec = 0;
    int error = ioctl(fd, SO_TIMESTAMP, &tv_ioctl);
    printf("%ld.%ld - error = %d", (long int)tv_ioctl.tv_sec, 
            (long int)tv_ioctl.tv_usec, error);
}
```

The output of the printf statement is always the following:

> > 0.0 error = -1

The error = -1 indicates that the ioctl call has failed. I've performed a test with `getsockopt` to check if the SO_TIMESTAMP option is set, `getsockopt` returns 0 for the option SO_TIMESTAMP so it seems correctly set. I'm a bit lost here, how can I further investigate why the ioctl call seems to be failing?

Comment: Looking to [THIS](https://vilimpoc.org/research/ku-latency/), it seems that `SO_TIMESTAMP` is used to set the option, not to retrieve data. You must use [recvmsg](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recvmsg) to get infos.

Comment: When you get an error from a system call you should print `errno` or `strerror()` or use `perror()` to do it for you. As you have discovered, -1 doesn't tell you anything useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ioctl to retrieve the most recent timestamp on the socket is `SIOCGSTAMP`; `SO_TIMESTAMP` is a socket option, not an ioctl. Your code should read:

```
int error = ioctl(fd, SIOCGSTAMP, &tv_ioctl);
                      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The alternate method to retrieve timestamps is to change `recv` to `recvmmsg` and extract the timestamp from the ancillary data. This is more efficient as it involves fewer system calls ([Socket reading and timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13304672/socket-reading-and-timestamps)); the ioctl is simpler, though.

Note that SIOCGSTAMP and SO_TIMESTAMP are mutually exclusive - if you're going to use SIOCGSTAMP you should **disable** SO_TIMESTAMP (with `enabled = 0`). This is because SO_TIMESTAMP directs the kernel to make the timestamp available via `recvmmsg` ancillary data instead of via SIOCGSTAMP.

Comment: I'm trying this now with SIOCGSTAMP, I've set SO_TIMESTAMP option to 0 with setsockopt. However the ioctl call is still returning -1. Must I enable the SIOCGSTAMP or can it be that it is not supported by the device driver?

Comment: @Gio what is `errno` set to? The only reason I'm aware that SIOCGSTAMP would fail is if SO_TIMESTAMP is enabled, in which case it would be set to ENOENT.

Comment: `printf("%s", strerror(errno))` prints  "No such file or directory".

Comment: @Gio that indicates that there is no timestamp available on that socket. There's nothing obviously wrong with what you're doing - maybe try running the timestamping example from the kernel documentation https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/timestamping/timestamping.c and see if you can get any of that to work.

Comment: I've discovered why it doesn't work. SIOCGSTAMP only works for UDP packets or RAW sockets, but does not work for TCP.

Comment: @Gio Have you found a way to obtain kernel level timestamps for TCP? Thanks!

Comment: @kirbo it doesn't make sense to ask for timestamps for TCP, because there's no direct correlation between arriving packets and data becoming available. If you really want timestamps for TCP you'll have to use RAW sockets and implement your own TCP stack (or use a userspace TCP library).